# OnRestoreInstanceState returning null after rotation

Tags: java, android, android-activity, kotlin

When i type something in listView and after that rotate it listView returns null instead of text i typed in. Can you please explain why is this happening.

```
override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)
        Log.i("ToDoList","OnRestoreInstanceState was called")

        val listSave = savedInstanceState?.getStringArrayList("list")
        this.list.clear()
        this.list.add(listSave.toString())

        adapter = ArrayAdapter <String> (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list)
        toDoList.adapter = adapter
    }
override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle?, outPersistentState: PersistableBundle?) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState)
        Log.i("ToDoList","OnSaveInstanceState was called")
        outState?.putStringArrayList("list", list)
    }
```

Comment: Have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12793069/android-onsaveinstancestate-not-being-called-from-activity. I guess, that your state is not saved, because the method is not called by the os.

Comment: It's not that i checked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Root cause:** You override wrong `onSaveInstanceState()` method.

**Solution:** You must override [onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)) instead of [onSaveInstanceState(Bundle, PersistableBundle)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle,%2520android.os.PersistableBundle)).

Change your code from

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle?, outPersistentState: PersistableBundle?) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState)
    Log.i("ToDoList","OnSaveInstanceState was called")
    outState?.putStringArrayList("list", list)
}
```

to

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle?) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    Log.i("ToDoList","OnSaveInstanceState was called")
    outState?.putStringArrayList("list", list)
}
```